# Can not use CSS modules in Nextjs, Ant Design?

Tags: less, next.js, antd, css-modules

I'm doing a NextJS project using Ant design, Less. But I can't use CSS modules with Less even when I add

> cssModules: true,

Here my next.config.js

```
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
const lessToJS = require('less-vars-to-js')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// Where your antd-custom.less file lives
const themeVariables = lessToJS(
    fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/antd-custom.less'), 'utf8')
)

module.exports = withLess({
    cssModules: true,
    lessLoaderOptions: {
        javascriptEnabled: true,
        modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
    },
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {

        if (isServer) {
            const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/
            const origExternals = [...config.externals]
            config.externals = [
                (context, request, callback) => {
                    if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback()
                    if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
                        origExternals[0](context, request, callback)
                    } else {
                        callback()
                    }
                },
                ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function' ? [] : origExternals),
            ]

            config.module.rules.unshift({
                test: antStyles,
                use: 'null-loader',
            })
        }
        return config
    },
})
```

index.js:

```
 import styles from 'path-to-less.less'


<p className={styles.styleTab1} >Conntents </p>
```

but I it doesn't effect to my component.

Comment: This problem is solved here => https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design-less

Comment: and here => https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? @Afsanefda references do not solve it, and those examples don't use CSS modules...

Comment: @mllm for css modules you have to go through webpack config and make CSS modules true, but in the latest version of nextjs the css is a built-in feature and it doesn't need any configuration unless you want to add sass or less.

Comment: @Afsanefda yes, I do want to add less, so obliged to use `@zeit/next-less` - and apparently passing `cssModules: true` to `withLess`, as documented [here](https://github.com/vercel/next-plugins/tree/master/packages/next-less#with-css-modules) makes Ant Design's styles disappear.

Comment: Which version of Nextjs this question was based on?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a solution:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8156#issuecomment-516009764

From my tries, this solution requires `@zeit/next-less`, `@zeit/next-css`, `less`, `less-loader` as dependencies ‍♂️.